# Google SDK API - update Workspace user profile data by service account (Not Authorized to access this resource/api)

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk

I am trying to sync our user profiles from our internal SaaS to Google Workspace user profiles. Especially (gender, phone, jobTitle, department).
After a long reading, I found out that it is not possible to do by OAuth in the Google cloud project, but it is necessary to create a service account. I have created it, but I am still getting responses **Not Authorized to access this resource/api**.

- The Domain-wide Delegation is enabled.
- Admin SDK API is enabled.
- API client access with scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" is enabled in Workspace security.

**Permission of service account:**
[image]

**Code:**

```php
        $config = __DIR__ . '/project-users.json';

        $client = new \Google\Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('project-users');
        $client->setAuthConfig($config);
        $client->addScope(Google_Service_Directory::ADMIN_DIRECTORY_USER);
        $client->setSubject('admin@domain.com');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');

        $gsdService = new \Google\Service\Directory($client);
        
        $googleUser = new \Google\Service\Directory\User();
        // Gender
        $gender = new \Google\Service\Directory\UserGender();
        $gender->setType('male');
        // Phone
        $phone = new \Google\Service\Directory\UserPhone();
        $phone->setType('mobile');
        $phone->setValue('123456789');
        $googleUser->setPhones([$phone]);
        // jobTitle and department
        $organization = new \Google\Service\Directory\UserOrganization();
        $organization->setPrimary(TRUE);
        $organization->setTitle('Lead Developer');
        $organization->setDepartment('Dev');
        $googleUser->setOrganizations([$organization]);
        
        $gsdService->users->update('fname.lname@domain.com', $googleUser);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### When using a service account with domain-wide delegation you need to impersonate a user who has the necessary authorization

- The Directory API method [users.update](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update) can only be executed by domain admins with the respective role / permissions.
- See [how to make a user an admin](https://support.google.com/a/answer/172176?hl=en).
- If in doubt, you can test with the [Try this API](Try this API) authorized as 'admin@domain.com' to verify either this user has the necessary permissions.

Comment: That is the third point I wrote: API client access with scope "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" is enabled in Workspace security.

Comment: In the admin console? If so, I did not understand you correctly.

Comment: Is 'admin@domain.com' authorized to perform the updates you are trying to? You can quickly verify it by testing with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/update?apix=true) authorized as 'admin@domain.com'.

Comment: No, the Try this API gives me the same response. That is probably the problem. The account 'admin@domain.com' is only for reading user data. It can't go anywhere else in Google Admin. If I understand correctly, even if I allow scopes on the service account level and the user has not permission, I can not access the endpoint...

Comment: You understood correctly. The idea of a service account with impersonation is to perform actions on behalf of a user who has the necessary permissions - in your case it would be a domain admin who has access to the the respective Admin Directory methods. I will update my solution, since in your case the problem is a different one than I initially assumed.

Comment: @ziganotschka What about without using domain-wide delegation? I have a Google Cloud service account configured with user admin permissions on Google Workspace and I can call the insert API to create users just fine from it but as soon as I try to update a user, I get the same "Not Authorized to access this resource/api." error. These docs https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#optional_set_up_domain-wide_delegation_for_a_service_account do mention that domain-wide delegation is optional but I can't seem to call the update API. Any thoughts on the matter?